# How to configure based on local OS information inside rails config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Inside of my Rails app's config files (config/environments/*.rb) I need to provide paths to some files needed to configure HTTPS.  I don't want to package these files themselves within my application itself because they're things like private key files.

What I'd like to do is check the local OS (whether it is Windows or Linux) and provide alternate paths based on that.  What can I call to get this information?

Comment: I'm just curious why you need https configuration information inside your rails app,  normally wouldn't you just configure HTTPS in the web server (Apache, IIS, whatever) and have at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this is helpful

```
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
    when /linux.*x86_64|x86_64.*linux/
      OS_PLATFORM = 'linux64'
    when /linux/
      OS_PLATFORM = 'linux32'
    when /darwin/
      OS_PLATFORM = 'darwin'
    else
      OS_PLATFORM = 'win32'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command-line example which outputs 'linux' on a Linux machine:

```
  ruby -e "require 'rbconfig'; puts Config::CONFIG['target_os']"
```